# python server socket closes immediately

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I have a simple server-client combo running on 2 computers in 2 different networks. The server (a Raspberry) has a TCP tunnel running.

Now running on the code on localhost is fine, on 2 different machines with correct IP and port (I can ping the server via `telnet` and establish connection via `ssh` using the same IP and port), I just get the following on the client side AND NOTHING ELSE:

Received `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Raspbian-10+deb10u2`

I should instead receive: `Received b'Hello, world'`

On the serverside I receive no message at all.

What do I need to run it in 2 different networks? Below the source codes.

server.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

HOST = ''  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print("Connected by", addr)
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            conn.sendall(data)
```

client.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket

HOST = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'  # The server's hostname or GLOBAL IP address
PORT = 12345 # The port used by the server, not actually 12345

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(b"Hello, world")
    data = s.recv(1024)

print("Received", repr(data))
```

Comment: What port *do* you actually use? The message implies you connect to sshd.

Comment: By "establish connection via ssh using the same IP and port" do you mean the same port used for ssh and your server? Are you aware that only one application can bind to a port at any time?

Comment: I can but I don't run both ssh and the client at the same time. I just wanted show that I know the correct IP address and port number.

Comment: Regarding your 1. question: Whatever pyhton's socket is using. I don't execute anything beyond the pair of code and the TCP tunneling on any of the 2 computers.

Comment: when you send message between two networks then it has to go through `router` - and it has to be configured to accept and forward messages from one network to another. It may do this for some ports and block for others.

Comment: *"The server (a Raspberry) has a TCP tunnel running."* - you are not connecting to the TCP tunnel but directly to the remote SSH server. If you have a SSH tunnel like `ssh -L1234:localhost:65432 remote-ssh-server` then you need to connect your client to 127.0.0.1 port 1234 in order to communicate _through the tunnel_ with the remote server.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich Does this mean, I should have a constantly running ssh connection and THEN start the client and the server?

Comment: @topkek: If your aim is to connect to the server through the tunnel, then the tunnel must be running. If your aim is to connect to the server directly then you must use the actual port where the server is running (i.e. 65432 in your example) - right now you seem to connect to the SSH server instead. Note that the server need to be reachable on this public IP address though, i.e. a server behind some NAT router or firewall will not be directly reachable unless specific rules or port forwarding allow this.

Comment: Ok, I guess it's behind NAT so that's not an option(silly me)... So the other option is a connection via `ssh` from local to remote (Raspberry) with `ssh <port-of-tunnel>:localhost:<arbitrary-non-priviledged-port> <remote-address>`and change the ports and hosts in the source codes to `localhost` (or `''`) and that `<arbitrary-non-priviledged-port>`?